# Accesing variables in Thymeleaf template and sending them back to Controller unchanged

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model, thymeleaf

I have Spring MVC web app using Thymeleaf on frontend. I can send data from Controller (adding to model as attributes) to Thymeleaf and showing them here. Now I want to save this data into database. But my question is: How to send the same object back to controller from thymeleaf?

Here I add attribute into model in Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/find")
    public String company(@RequestParam("companyId") String companyID, Model model) {

        Company company = dataService.find(companyID);      

        model.addAttribute("company", company);


        return "company-find";
    }
```

In Thymeleaf I can access the company informations like company name (th:text="${company.name}") without problem. But how easily can I send this same company into controller?
Trying this, but it dont work:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/companyadd}"  method="POST" th:object="${company}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Add company to database</button>
    </form>
```

**EDIT**

In my controller I have this mapping for company from Thymeleaf. But inside this method the company is null :(

```
@PostMapping("/companyadd")
    public String companyAdd(@ModelAttribute("company") Company company) {
        
        dataService.add(company);

        return "company-add";
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

I need to fill the model with attributes. I can do this, but I have troubles if the attribute is not a String. Two attributes of this collections are List, but I dont know how to insert them into model :/.
Code below works (atributes are String), but I need to insert a collection there as well.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addcompany}"  method="POST" th:object="${company}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{address}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{capital}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Add company to database</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form, you have to add the properties corresponding to your object company. `th:object="${company}"` just declares the model object to use for collecting the form data.

Here you can find the example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Answer (score 1):

For fields that you just want to copy to the new object, you can use hidden fields. For example:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/companyadd}"  method="POST" th:object="${company}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Add company to database</button>
</form>
```

Then "company.id" will be copied from the company object sent in the GET handler to the company object received in the POST handler. That should be enough information to save the changes or look up the rest of the fields.

But be warned: Any user can easily change what's in hidden fields by editing the HTML. So don't assume that the information is correct or trustworthy just because it came from a hidden field. In this example you should double check to make sure that user can actually access that ID before saving.

Comment: Great, it works! But some company attributes are collections. How can I do this with collection?

Comment: I would suggest doing only the minimum necessary information this way, such as the ID, and then looking up the rest of the information again in the POST handler. As mentioned the user can easily manipulate things in hidden fields.

However it is possible to achieve: [[sorry, editing...]]

Comment: Cont'd... However it is possible to achieve. For example to copy all of the company.employees[].id fields: `<input type="hidden" th:each="row,rowStat : *{employees}" th:field="*{employees[__${rowStat.index}__].id}" />` See also: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

Answer (score 0):

You might add a POST endpoint to your controller like this:

```java
    @PostMapping("/companyadd")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCompany(@RequestBody Company company) {
        dataService.save(company);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```